# UIInterpolatingMotionEffect within SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to use UIInterpolatingMotionEffect within SwiftUI. I was thinking to use the coordinator as a way to bridge between UIKit ans SwiftUI with no success. I want to change the amount of shadow of a rounded rectangle depending on the tilting of the iPhone. Any idea to achive this. Maybe it is possible to get the underlying UIVie for this.

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    static let offWhite = Color(red: 225 / 255, green: 225 / 255, blue: 235 / 255)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var x_tilt = 10.0
    @State var y_tilt = 10.0


    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Color.offWhite
            VStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .fill(Color.offWhite)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2),
                        radius: 10,
                        x: CGFloat(x_tilt),
                        y: CGFloat(y_tilt))
                .shadow(color: Color.white.opacity(0.7),
                        radius: 10,
                        x: CGFloat(5 + (-0.5 * x_tilt)),
                        y: CGFloat(5 + (-0.5 * y_tilt))
                 )
                 Slider(value: $x_tilt, in: -10...30, step: 1)
                 Text("X: \(x_tilt)")
                 Slider(value: $y_tilt, in: -10...30, step: 1)
                 Text("Y: \(-0.5 * y_tilt)")
            }

         }
         .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
     }
 }



 struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
     static var previews: some View {
         ContentView()
    }
 }
```

I would like to use the motion sensor (tilting) to change the `x_tilt` and `y_tilt` values dynamically. I simulate this right now with the two sliders.

Comment: Would you show your code?